# How to read value from the peripheral in BT4.0?

Tags: iphone, ios6, core-bluetooth

I'm developing an app with BT 4.0.
My central manager is scanning for peripherals and connecting to one of them that its found.
The problem is that I can't found how to read a value for characteristic from the connected peripheral..
I've watched WWDC2012 and it didn't help..
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CBPeripheral once the device is connected:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheral_Class/translated_content/CBPeripheral.html

Answer (score 3):

check this app link..Hope this help for you

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lightblue/id557428110?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4